# ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: "ffmpeg and Android.mk")

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, cross-compiling, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to compile ffmpeg for a android. I have found several posts on this theme but non of these seems to work. If tried to build ffmpeg like it is posted on [1]. Did anybody successfully compile ffmpeg using theses tutorial?
I am not sure how to realize step 4  to 5.

> STEP4: Configuring ...
>
> STEP5: cd to your NDK root dir, type make TARGET_ARCH=arm APP=ffmpeg-org

It seems to me that building an application like it is explained in the tutorial in step 5 need some previous steps. Unfortunately I have no app in the folder to make. I am using the current android ndk release 3 and checked out the actual ffmpeg releases from [3] and [4]. I am thankful for every advice.

[1] http://slworkthings.wordpress.com/
[2] http://gitorious.org/~olvaffe/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-android
[3] http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: I've looked through all the replies here and in many other sites and there does not appear to be a definitive guide to compiling, building and using ffmpeg (in a Windows environment) for Android. It would be extremely useful to be able to nail this.

Comment: I found following link, which works http://rowntreerob.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/ffmpeg-on-android-adding-vmware-and-ubuntu-to-best-practice/

Answer (score 21):

After looking around the net. The only working solution I found is supplied by Bambuser which ported ffmpeg to use in their android application.

Code is here: http://bambuser.com/opensource

Basically you copy the .so files to your jni/lib directory, along with any .h files you might need, create a JNI wrapper through javah, and it works.

***EDIT:***

Since this post was written a few packaged ffmpeg projects for android surfaced, one of the easiest ones to compile and use is here: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg .

It  takes the approach of statically compiling a binary (not a library) that is ran through shell command in run time. Search github for '`android ffmpeg`' for forks and related projects.

Did not find a well packaged method based JNI implementation, though.

Comment: Don't you need a C or C++ file which can make calls into the shared libraries or can these calls be made with the header files?

Comment: could you elaborate on that (also on @John's question)? Have you got it to work?

Comment: Hey, @Guy, do you think you could please elaborate how you got this to work? Possibly with some code examples and instructions?

Answer (score 4):

I found a guide on ffmpeg on android here:
http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/05/use-ffmpeg-to-setup-streaming-server-on.html

He explains in another post how he got to do native programming on android to install ffmpeg. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In NDK r3, when you use the `make` command, the NDK will simply use the name of the folder in the "apps" folder for the name of your project.  This assumes that you have your FFmpeg source files and `android.mk` somewhere within `NDK/apps/ffmpeg-org/jni/`

In otherwords, ensure that your foldername is set to `ffmpeg-org`.

EDIT: You might find it worthwile to use NDK r4 which changes `make` to `ndk-build`.  In this new NDK, you don't need to have your project set up in any particular way, as `ndk-build` simply searches your project for `Android.mk` files to tell it what to compile.

Answer (score 3):

I will provide a more **updated** list of sources which will explain how to build and, in some cases, even use `FFMPEG` on Android.

This is the guide I liked the most: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

If you need more options, you can take a look at these, which are *equally good*:

- https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg
- https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264
- https://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk

Comment: https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg appears to be quite good too. But it's a video player, and I need a transcoder, so your second link to **android-ffmpeg-x264** looks suitable, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue currently, there is an excellent library to FFmpeg on android. This library is up to date and well maintained.

Here is the link for that: https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/