# Video Encoding Problem

Tags: android

All I want is to put some video to my server and play it in my application. I tried many of 3rd party applications to change video encoding. None of them works. Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is using two software:

- First convert video to mp4 using `Sothink` by selecting `Mobile Phone Encoding`.
- Then use `MP4Box` console application with `-hint`.

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried FFMPEG library? you can use this library with android ndk for your application. try [FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android), [ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: “ffmpeg and Android.mk”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk) and [How to Build Android Applications Based on FFmpeg by An Example](http://www.roman10.net/?p=394)

For build ffmpeg [How to Build FFmpeg for Android](http://www.roman10.net/?p=389).

Comment: Yes I tried, but I will try these examples. Actually, using Sothing Video Converter and then usign Mp4Box is working. But I don't want to use two different software to play a video.

Comment: I think ffmpeg will worked, Bcoz in my case m able to play the file using FFMPEG. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, for working purpose can you encode the videos on server after encoded it use it in your android application, I think its easiest way for you. And also you will find many video encoders for your server machine. Thanks.