# How to convert video format mov to 3gp or mp4 in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to convert video format mov to 3gp or mp4 in android.can anybody provide example

Thanks

Comment: i think you need a software for convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andriod natively does not have such functionality. The easiest would be to use a video decoding/encoding library, such as `ffmpeg`. See this: [ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: "ffmpeg and Android.mk")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk)