# Playback RTP using Android media player

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player

I want to playback RTP video session that is being send to my tablet through a socket port , but the media player in android 3.0 only support RTSP or file sources , what is the best way to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with Android SDK. There is even an issue to resolve this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8959&q=rtp&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Your best option would be to explore using [ffmpeg under Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk).

Answer (score 0):

the easy way:

download videolan.
and check this [how to streaming with videolan](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aStreaming_HowTo/Easy_Streaming_Newer_Versions)

the "complicated" way is creating a server with gstreamer rtspserver, darwin... real... etc