# Download first frame of video android programmatically

Tags: android, video, download, frame

I want to download a single frame of a video file from a server from my android application. I do not wat to download the full video at front. Use that frame as a thumbnail to display to the user, so that if choosen by user it can be downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ffmpeg` can create a thumbnail from a video stream using this command:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset -4  -i http://somevideosite/test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1\
       -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 thumb.jpg
```

*To get `ffmpeg` into android seems [doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk).*

Comment: Use the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if your server provided thumbnails for each video like youtube/dailymotion does. You could create this thumbnail when video is added to the server.

Ex: http://img.youtube.com/vi/`<VIDEO_ID>`/`<1,2,3>`.jpg