# How to get Online Video Thumbnail without download in android

Tags: android, video-thumbnails

I need to get the thumbnail of an online video file without downloading the file.

Is it possible ?

Is it possible with Universal Image Loader ?

Comment: Does the website hold thumbnails?

Comment: @CliveDM unfortunately No !

Comment: @HK there is no way to get video thumbnail without downloading of video

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever .. I hope it helps you. It is MediaMetadataRetriverLibrary ....

Comment: Could you build a custom web service to do this server-side, then hit that service from your mobile app?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to get online video thumbnail without downloading of video completely using in-built android API but using [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11046654/1686269)

We can extract thumbnail from downloaded video using below method.

```
ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)
```

where

`filePath` the path of video file

`kind` could be MINI_KIND or MICRO_KIND

Return value

```
May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported.
```

I have created demo application for you. Please find path of android project which is uploaded on github [AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/AndroidDaily/AndroidFFmpeg)

Execute below command to extract first frame from online video url:

**Syntax:**

```
-itsoffset -4 -i [Url of online video] -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 [Path of image where thumbnail to be stored]
```

**For Example:**

-itsoffset -4 -i http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 /sdcard/thumb.jpg

This will generate thumbnail image on SDCard with resolution 320x240 with name thumb.jpg

Comment: Min-SDK : 10 , So i have to download first frame of video?! how ?

Comment: @HK look at my updated answer and give your feedback for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is no easy way to build the thumbnail without actually downloading the video locally.

So if your question is 'Can I get a thumbnail without having to download the full video?', I'd say...no.

Otherwise, once you have downloaded the video locally, then I guess you can perfectly use `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(...)`by giving the path to the downloaded file.

and other option for creating video thumb:

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( videoUrl, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

enjoy your code:)

Answer (score -1):

In some specific scenarios, 
1 - if HTML5 video tag contains poster in it, you can parse the page to find its value. 
2 - If by any chance site is youtube , the answer is here >>[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)