# How can I store JPEGs as Byte[] for faster loading?

Tags: android

I need to load ~150 JPEG images into ArrayList for playing an animation.

If I load them like that

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y1).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
byeArr.add( stream.toByteArray() );
```

it can take up to ~10 seconds for 150 images, so maybe there is a way to speed it up? Can I somehow store this images in resources or in assets already as byte[] or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method below to get the raw data from a resource. You don't need to decode then compress again.

```
byte[] getBytesFromResource(final int res) {
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = getResources().openRawResource(res);
        buffer = new byte[input.available()];
        if (input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != buffer.length) {
            buffer = null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        buffer = null;
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: @RogerTravis you can accept the answer then :) You can not run away from decode time while decoding images other than that this technique should help you. In case decoding is slow play with jpegs compressions etc. That might help.