# Android 2.x App to play mp4 with H.264

Tags: android, video, mp4

Android 2.x does not play mp4 with H.264 baseband from scratch.

However, some apps are able to manage this when playing the video files in-app.

How to append the encoder/decoder to the videoplayer within the app to make sure, that this format is supported without external dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These apps integrate some media library (as example [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/))

However, explaining how to compile, integrate and use such library is well beyond stack overflow scope.

If you are interested how to do this. Read following questions/articles:

[FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

[ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: "ffmpeg and Android.mk")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/