# Running FFMPEG in Android

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, video-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: “ffmpeg and Android.mk”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk)

I have tried several things running FFMPEG in android, searched around the whole net,No fruitful or direct solutions available. Refereed [this](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/) and related was very helpful though.

Moreover currently I am able to build the FFMPEG in Ubuntu 12. Created all the .SO binary everything.

My question is, how do I change the ffmeg.c file which will enable me to pass ffmpeg commands ?

According to [this](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-port-ffmpeg-the-program-to-androidideas-and-thoughts/) by following steps this is possible.

With the design above, the change for ffmpeg.c is simple.

```
Change the main(int argc, char **argv) function prototype to a java JNI interface prototype that Android java code can call.
Change the output to stdout to the text files we created.
Comment out a few lines that cause the compilation error.
```

But I'm unable to change the main and how it would be.

Please help me on this. If somebody have already achieved this thing.

Comment: Its not a duplicate. My question is different.