# How i can convert video file to .mov file extension

Tags: android, video, video-conversion

I am developing an android application. In that I have to convert all the video files to '.mov' file extension. Is it possible to do in android app? Please guide me.

Comment: There isn't native functionality for this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2645041/1072229.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

here are some useful references:

1. http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
2. https://www.labnol.org/internet/useful-ffmpeg-commands/28490/
3. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ffmpeg-guide/
4. https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this that I found but there are many conversion websites like [this](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-video-for-android)